# Passing extra context around a form

Tags: django

I have two models, `Board` and `Problem`.  Each `Board` has many `Problem` linked to it.

```
class Board(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Problem(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    problem = models.TextField()
```

Then I have a page where I can update values in an individual `Problem` instance.

```
class ProblemStudyView(UpdateView):
    model = Problem
    fields = "__all__"
    template_name = "board/study.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        success_url = reverse_lazy('board:problem-study', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
        return success_url
```

This makes a fine form for updating the `Problem`.  But I'd like to add two more url's, "previous Problem" and "next Problem".  These would be links to the same `ProblemStudyView` for the next or previous Problem that shares the same parent `Board`.

My problem is that I don't know where in the `ProblemStudyView` class I can generate this context to feed to the template.  I would need to run two queries -- "what is the parent board of this current Problem" and "what is the list of Problems that share this common parent Board?"  Then I can indicate the previous and next `Problem` to consider

This seems kind of convoluted,  so I am guessing I'm missing some more clever way to do this while still enjoying the use of an `UpdateView`-based class.

===========================================
UPDATE

I override the get_context_data() method, but I am struggling to figure out how to refer to the original `Problem` so that I can generate the context i need.

The `ProblemStudyView` was originally passed a `Problem` to make the form.  But I don't know how to refer to that `Problem` inside the `get_context_data` method.  My best guess was `self.Problem.board`  but  `Problem` is not a field of `ProblemStudyView`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProblemStudyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    parent = self.Problem.board
    all_children = Problem.objects.filter(board = parent)
    context['foo'] = F"{len(all_children)} children available"

    return context
```

==============================================

Bear Brown's amendments:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    #problem?  I changed the parameters passed to method
    #get_context_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
    #context = super(ProblemStudyView, self).get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
    context = super(ProblemStudyView, self).get_context_data( **kwargs)

    #But I still have no way to get the Problem
    #ProblemStudyView' object has no attribute 'Problem'
    items = self.Problem.board.problem_set.all().order_by('pk')


    # page number just count problems with less or equaul pk
    page = items.filter(pk__lte=self.Problem.pk).count()
    # initial django paginator with 1 item per page
    paginator = Paginator(items, 1)
    # add pagination to the context
    context['pagination'] = paginator.page(page)
    context['foo']="new version"
    return context
```

======================

final...

```
    #my version
    #the_problem = get_object_or_404(Problem, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    #all_problems = the_problem.board.problem_set.all().order_by('pk')

    #bear's version
    all_problems = self.get_object().board.problem_set.all().order_by('pk')
```

I didn't know the `self.get_object()` method.  That's what I needed.  Bear's is probably more robust/correct way to do it than my backdoor get_object_or_404 hack, too...  At least saves that database access anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override `get_context_data`

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

class ProblemStudyView(UpdateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProblemStudyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # all parent board problems order by pk -- change order if need
        items = self.get_object().board.problem_set.all().order_by('pk')
        # page number just count problems with less or equaul pk
        page = items.filter(pk__lte=self.Problem.pk).count()
        # initial django paginator with 1 item per page
        paginator = Paginator(items, 1)
        # add pagination to the context
        context['pagination'] = paginator.page(page)

        return context
```

Comment: Yes, I did see that I can overwrite the method.   The hangup now is that I am not sure how to get a reference to the Problem object which was used to set up the View in the first place.   There are so many Mixin inheritances to this view that I cannot identify the way to retrieve it.  (I edited my original post to demonstrate what i was trying)

Comment: added new version hope it help you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that. Encountered two problems.  I pasted the revised code in the post.  1) the .get_context_data(self, **kwargs)  threw an error (get_context_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given)  so I removed the self parameter.    2)  I still have the same issue as before,  I cannot access the original Problem (ProblemStudyView' object has no attribute 'Problem')

Comment: i was think you add extra property for it, now i updated the answer

Comment: ahhhhh  `get_object()` -- I didn't know that method.  Thanks,  that fixed it.  Appreciate all your help.   I think that's better than the solution I found: 
 `get_object_or_404(Problem, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])`

Comment: to be clear to other readers... the `get_object()` method comes from the `SingleObjectMixin` that my own `UpdateView` inherits from.